# Is there a way of making a text inside a JLabel have different colors without html?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I'm trying to have a String that has differend colors like

"*(red:)* **##h-o3** *(yellow:)* **.5**"

Is there a way to achieve this without using html tags? It's hard to explain, but I can't use html tags for my code because if I did nothing else would work anymore.

Comment: What does not work if you `<html>`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I set the colour of a label (coloured text) in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2966334/how-do-i-set-the-colour-of-a-label-coloured-text-in-java)

Comment: Use a JTextPane. You can set attributes for each character. You can make the text pane transparent  and make it non-editable etc so it looks more like a label. See: for a simple example to get you started.

Comment: @Tikka You said it's hard to explain.  Can you elaborate just a little on why you can't use html?

Answer (score 0):

No, your'e have to use HTML or `JTextPane`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't post answers on obviously off topic/bad questions! [See: **Should one advise on off topic questions?**](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276572)